# A word of at least 5 letters is made at random from 3 vowels and 3 consonants, all the letters being different.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

The probability that no consonant falls between any two vowels in the word is

1. 9/20
2. 9/10
3. 7/10
4. 11/20

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

Consider two cases:

Case 1. $6$-letter words. $3!$ ways to permute $3$ vowels. $4!$ ways to permute block of $3$ vowels and $3$ consonants. $6!$ ways to permute $6$ letters in total. Hence:
$$\frac{3!\cdot 4!}{6!}$$
Case 2. $5$-letter words. a) $2$ vowels and $3$ consonants; b) $3$ vowels and $3$ consonants:
$$a) \ \frac{2!\cdot 4!}{5!}; \ b) \ \frac{3!\cdot 3!}{5!}.$$
Can you interpret Case 2 and finish?